# Chrome doesn't support silverlight anymore? How to solve this?

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight

In 2015, [Chrome doesn't support silverlight anymore](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/devtoolsguy/archive/2015/02/16/no-more-npapi-support-for-chrome-what-are-the-alternatives.aspx). So my app can't run on Chrome, but Firefox,... is run normally.
Silverlight can be run Out-Of browser, but it happen when we can access to the page, right click and install out of browser. But now Chrome doesn't let me access to silverlight.

So how to solve this problem?

1. I notice to my users use another browser like firefox, opera,....
2. ????

Comment: Jordan... hope that comment was laced with sarcasm.  Html for LOB applications are not built with html... horizontal perhaps....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Silverlight disappearing from Chrome 45, what are my alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685450/with-silverlight-disappearing-from-chrome-45-what-are-my-alternatives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silverlight not working with chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898021/silverlight-not-working-with-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Your clients need to enable the NPAPI manually in chrome. It is now deactivated by default.  This can be done by using

```
chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
```

in the address bar of chrome.

Here is a [link](http://support.panopto.com/documentation/admin-and-setup/troubleshooting/enabling-silverlight-plugin-npapi-plugins-chrome) to a walktrough to activate it.

**UPDATE:**

Since Chrome 45 NPAPI is completly gone from Chrome, but there seem to be workarounds. (See also [With Silverlight disappearing from Chrome 45, what are my alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685450/with-silverlight-disappearing-from-chrome-45-what-are-my-alternatives))

Comment: In the latest version of chrome this work around has be completely removed

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** The answer below is valid for Chrome versions 42-44 only. Please refer to the Jehof's answer above for a workaround in versions 45+.

Since version 42, Chrome blocks *Netscape Plugin API (NPAPI)* plugins from being displayed in the browser. See [KB 30582554](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058254) for details.

**To work around this issue:**

1. On the address bar in Chrome, type [chrome://flags/#enable-npapi](http://chrome://flags/#enable-npapi).
2. In the Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows box, click Enable.
3. Exit and then restart Chrome.
4. Open the [Silverlight page](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx) to check.
5. Right-click the broken puzzle piece image, and then select Run this Plugin.

Comment: In the latest version of chrome this work around has be completely removed