# How to activate silverlight on chrome version 62+?

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight

I could not activate Silverlight on the new version of Google Chrome (62). The steps that defined on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898021/silverlight-not-working-with-chrome) it does not work. I could not find NPAPI in the "chrome://flags/#enable-npapi" to enable it.

Answer (score -1):

NPAPI is permanently removed from chrome in sep 2015.